# How to stop video in tabs?

Tags: jquery, video, tabs

I have a tab interface on my website that contains images and a youtube video on the last tab. All works fine however everytime I switch tabs the video doesn't stop playing. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Here's the script for the tabs:

```
$("#simple-tabs .tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
$("#simple-tabs ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
$("#simple-tabs .tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

//On Click Event
$("#simple-tabs ul.tabs li").click(function(e) {
    $("#simple-tabs ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $("#simple-tabs .tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
    e.preventDefault();
});


(function ($) { 
        $('.tab ul.tabs li:first-child a').addClass('current');
        $('.tab .tab_content div.tabs_tab:first-child').show();

        $('.tab ul.tabs li a').click(function (g) { 
            var tab = $(this).parent().parent().parent(), 
                index = $(this).parent().index();

            tab.find('ul.tabs').find('a').removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');

            tab.find('.tab_content').find('div.tabs_tab').not('div.tabs_tab:eq(' + index + ')').slideUp();
            tab.find('.tab_content').find('div.tabs_tab:eq(' + index + ')').slideDown();

            g.preventDefault();
        } );
    } )(jQuery);
```

And here's the HTML markup:

```
<div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
   <div class="video-container">
     <iframe width="510" height="270" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/6Cf7IL_eZ38" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can control the video with the [youtube iframe api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), so load the JS like:

```
<script src="//www.youtube.com/iframe_api" />
```

Then put an `id` attribute on the iframe like:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" ... >
```

And you should be able to stop it like this:

```
player = document.getElementById('ytplayer');

function stop(){
    player.stopVideo();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!But both ways didn't work and I just can't figure out what is wrong :(

Comment: how do I put an id attribute to the iframe? Is it something like this <iframe name="name">  or is it <iframe id="player">

Comment: @user1628193 it's `<iframe id="ytplayer" ... >` for my example code

Comment: @user1628193 you also have to load the JS, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your effort to try to help me but somehow it didn't work.
Here's a link for my tabs maybe it will be easier for u if u see it
http://jsfiddle.net/EPEDr/1/